# Draw scatter plot with crosshair on each data points in iReport

Tags: java, javascript, jasper-reports, ireport, pentaho

Is it possible to draw scatter chart with horizontal and vertical line on the specific data-point in *iReport* or any other reporting tool except *Excel*?

Comment: Can you illustrate your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, as iReport Charts are based on the JFreeChart Library and you can bind a ChartCustomizer to your chart in iReport, that should not be a big problem.

Search google for these catchwords and you'll get ahead.